# How to call name attribute for dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I am currently using dropzone to let users upload images. I haven't made many changes to the original dropzone code.All works fine until the user clicks on the submit button, as soon as the images are submitted to submit.php, I receive an error message saying undefined index 'file'. How can receive the files posted through the form.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dropzone.js"></script>
       <section>
           <p class="scroll-invitation">
           <a href="#try-it-out"><span></span></a>
           </p>
            <div id="dropzone">
            <form action="submit.php" class="dropzone needsclick" id="my-awesome-upload">
            <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            Drag and drop or click to Upload.<br />
          </div> 
        </form>
     </div>
     </section>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php

   // Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    echo "FILES =".json_encode($_FILES)."<br><br>";
  }

?>
```

For some reason my php throwing below error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\submit.php on line 4.
```

My understanding is the I need to use paramName as file but can't figure out how to fix it.